# Qiskit - How to prepare this superposition from general states?

Tags: qiskit, circuit-construction, quantum-circuit

I have two general states represented by circuits $|\psi_A\rangle$ and $|\psi_B \rangle$. I'd like to prepare the superposition
$$
|+^y_{AB}\rangle = \frac{|\psi_A\rangle + i|\psi_B\rangle}{\sqrt{2}},
$$

as described in *Nakanishi, K. M., Mitarai, K., & Fujii, K. (2019). Subspace-search variational quantum eigensolver for excited states. Physical Review Research, 1(3), 033062.*

I'd be able to do something similar, if there was no imaginary number before $|\psi_B\rangle$, as it could look similar to this, with different angle.

[image]

But in this case, while I have a feeling, it should be a generally-known identity, I'm lost - do you know, how to do it?